# Using Nav Mesh Agent to the object in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I added a Nav Mesh Agent Component to animated object and now instead of following the player he always goes to the (0,0,0) position.Any suggestions??

(Unity Survival Shooter tutorial!)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
Transform player;
NavMeshAgent nav;


void Awake ()
{
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player").transform;

    nav = GetComponent <NavMeshAgent> ();
}


void Update ()
{

        nav.SetDestination (player.position);

}
}
```

Comment: try add "Debug.Log("Name: "+player.name);" after player has been set in Awake, to see if the name printed in the console is the name of the expected player. Also write "Debug.Log("Position: "+player.position);" Then add the result as a screenshot to your post.

Comment: Hmm,the name is "Environment" and the position is (0,0,0)!! that's make sense))))

Comment: I solved it,thak you!!

Comment: np, just be more descriptive from the beginning when you post in the future :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A NavMeshAgent as opposed to? What was previously making it move? Show the scripts that make it move. You need to add more information about what your are doing when you post questions.

**A NavMeshAgent needs to have a Vector3 destination set which you will typically get from a Transform, in this case if the player is the target the players Transform.**

The script setting it can for example be:

```
Using UnityEngine.AI;

NavMeshAgent agent;

public float UpdatePositionCooldown = 0.2f;
float UpdatePositionTime;
public Transform Player; //<-- Should be dragged in via inspector in this example

void Awake(){
    agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    UpdatePositionTime = Time.time;
}

void Update(){
    //Set destination if cooldown done.
    if (Time.time > UpdatePositionTime){
    agent.SetDestination(Player.position);
    UpdatePositionTime = UpdatePositionCooldown + Time.time;
    }
}
```

More information and source: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent.SetDestination.html

Comment: I added the script that moves the object!